# php Associative array content printing to screen

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which returns the content inside the function. I have an array with a mixture of string, intereger, dates, and doubles.

```
my_function(){
 $return_content = '';
 /* Contents of myArray are 
 Category1[0] = [0]; category[0][0] = example1; category[0][1] = '0'; category[0][2] = 2020-01-01; category[0][3] = 'This is example text;
Category2[0] = [0]; category[1][0] = example2; category[1][1] = '25'; category[1][2] = 2021-01-01; category[1][3] = 'This is example text; */

//When i return my array with the below statement it displays the above text.
$return_content .= myArray

//But when i return 
$return_content .= $myArray[0]; /* or */ $return_content .= $myArray[0][1];
// Nothing comes up


return $return_content;


}
```

How can i single out my data to read just the set of myArray[0] or even if i wanted to get more specific myArray[0][1].

Comment: This command `$return_content .= $myArray;` will not print anything to a screen it concatenates what in `$return_content` with `$myArray[0]` and sets `$return_content` with that value. It is short for `$return_content = $return_content . $myArray[0];`

Comment: You may need to clarify this a bit more I am not sure what you are doing or where the issue is and how you are seeing it.

Comment: I edited my code so you can see how it does its returns

Comment: post your actual array. What you have there is not real...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you need. Really I have no idea what the .= was being used for.

Pass in variables over using global.

I have no idea what the logic is to get a specific index so you will need to fill in that logic...

```
//This is the assumed structure. 
//If you want help with actuall data make sure to provided clean usable data...
$category = array( 
    ['example1', 0,'2020-01-01','This is example text'],
    ['example2',25,'2021-01-01','This is example text']
);

//Needed the function key word.
//First pass things into a function as a parameter
function my_function($multi_array){
    //Use the param name as the current function scopes variable

    //Not sure why you were using .= just return what you want?
    return $multi_array[0][1];
}

//Need to call the function to make it run
$retValue = my_function($category);

echo $retValue; //With current data outputs 0
```